# Binding ViewModel and TextFields with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I'm looking for the best way to create a bind between `textfields` and `ViewModel`. 
At the moment I'm creating a `@State` for each textfield and I'm manually sending the value from textfield to the viewModel properties when needed. I'm pretty sure this is not the best way to go... Is there a way to bind the `TextField` with the `ViewModel` property?

This is my current code:

```
struct SigninView: View {
    @State var username:String = ""
    @State var password:String = ""

    var viewModel:SignInViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15.0){

            DefaultTextField(placeholder: "username", value: $username)
            DefaultTextField(placeholder: "password", value: $password)

            Spacer()

            FillButton(title:"Sign In"){
                ///// IS THIS CORRECT?
                self.viewModel.email = self.username
                self.viewModel.password = self.password
                //------------------
                self.viewModel.signin()
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

The view model is something like:

```
class SignInViewModel:ObservableObject{

    var username:String? = nil
    var password:String? = nil
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think we can simplify it with below code.

```
class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""
}


struct SigninView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SignInViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15.0){

            TextField("username", text: $viewModel.username)
            TextField("password", text: $viewModel.password)

            Spacer()

            Button("Sign In"){
                print("User: \(self.viewModel.username)")
                print("Pass: \(self.viewModel.password)")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: won't this cause an additional view update due to the viewmodel being observed and its published members changing from the view?

Comment: @giorashc the concept of observer itself here is to update the UI when the view model changes or get the text in the text fields into a variable when the user types.

Answer (score 21):

Here is possible approach (of course I don't have your custom views, so just replaced with standard, but the idea is the same). Tested with Xcode 11.2/iOS 13.2

```
class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject{

    @Published var username:String? = nil
    @Published var password:String? = nil
}


struct SigninView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SignInViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15.0){

            TextField("username", text: Binding<String>(
                get: {self.viewModel.username ?? ""},
                set: {self.viewModel.username = $0}))
            TextField("password", text: Binding<String>(
                get: {self.viewModel.password ?? ""},
                set: {self.viewModel.password = $0}))

            Spacer()

            Button("Sign In"){
                print("User: \(self.viewModel.username)")
                print("Pass: \(self.viewModel.password)")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```