# Can SwiftUI Text Fields work with optional Bindings? : Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'

Tags: swiftui, option-type

Can SwiftUI Text Fields work with optional Bindings?

```
import SwiftUI


struct CategoryListDetail: View {
  
    @Binding var firstCategory : Category?
    

    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Section(header: Text("Category")){
                TextField("Category Name", text: $firstCategory.name)
            }
            Toggle("Availability",isOn: $firstCategory.availability)
        }
    }
}
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Here is the Category Entity

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Category {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Category> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Category>(entityName: "Category")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var availability: Bool
    @NSManaged public var sortOrder: Int64

}

extension Category : Identifiable {

}
```

Comment: But then what happens when it _is_ nil? Force unwrap (potential crash)? Or default string?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59566387/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543882/cannot-convert-value-of-type-bindingstring-to-expected-argument-type-bindi)