# How can I pass an object property as binding in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a UserService class with an optional user variable.

```
struct User: Codable {
    var id, first_name, last_name, dob: String
}

class UserService : ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
}
```

I pass this object from a view to another view in NavigationLink.

```
NavigationLink(destination: EditProfileView(userService: userService).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), isActive: $editProfileScreenActive){
                    Text("")
                }
```

In EditProfileView I was not able to use the properties of User in TextField.
e.g.

```
TextField("first_name", text: $userService.user?.first_name)
```

I tried different approaches but was not able to pass first_name as a binding to TextField. I am getting different kinds of compilation errors.

Any suggestions how to fix this? (I am not an experienced swift programmer :) )

Comment: Here is possible approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/59566387/12299030.

Comment: The problem is lonely the optional. Make it non optional.

Comment: Is `UserService` only dealing with one `User` or an [User]`?

Comment: only one `User` (current user)

Answer (score 0):

As the user is optional and `TextField` expects a non optional String as the text parameter, you have to first check if the user is not `nil`.

```
if let user = Binding($userService.user) {
    TextField("first_name", text: user.firstName)
}
```

However, if you still want to have a text field when the user is `nil` (this depends on what you are trying to achieve on this screen, I cannot determine this from your question), you might simply want to have an `@State` variable that you initialise with the users first name.

Answer (score -1):

Check by making a shared let, equal to `User`. Like this:

```
struct User: Codable {
    static let shared = User()
    var id, first_name, last_name, dob: String
}
```

So now you only have to type `User.shared.propertyName`